# wrong recyclerview item position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

my recyclerview is great in scrolling but when it contains more than two items and click on last item or the one before it gives me the wrong position this is
and throws a NullPointerException this is my whole code from adapter to the listener.
 **my code :**

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

private List<ItemView> items;
private Context context;

public ListAdapter(List<ItemView> items, Context context) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_style, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ItemView i = items.get(position);

    ViewHolder.setHeadText(i.getHead());
    ViewHolder.setScoreText(i.getContent());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

}

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private RecyclerViewOnTouchItemListener.ClickListener clickListener;
private static TextView headText, urlText;
private ConstraintLayout itemLayout;

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    headText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_header);
    urlText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_content);
    itemLayout = (ConstraintLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_list);
    // itemLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public static void setHeadText(String headText) {
    ViewHolder.headText.setText(headText);
}

public static void setScoreText(String scoreText) {
    ViewHolder.urlText.setText(scoreText);
}

public static String getHeadText(){return headText.getText().toString();}

public static String getUrlText(){return urlText.getText().toString();}
```

}

```
class RecyclerViewOnTouchItemListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerViewOnTouchItemListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) { }
@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) { }

interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);
    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
```

}

and this is the activity that holds the recyclerview :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_url_list);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    database = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    listOfUrl = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.url_list);
    find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findBtn);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

    makeItPopUp();

    listOfUrl.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listOfUrl.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listOfUrl.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    adapter = new ListAdapter(fillList(), context);
    listOfUrl.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    selectedItems = new ArrayList<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[listOfUrl.getAdapter().getItemCount()]));
    Collections.fill(selectedItems, Boolean.FALSE);

    listOfUrl.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerViewOnTouchItemListener(this, listOfUrl
                    , new RecyclerViewOnTouchItemListener.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                    if (selectedItems.get(position))
                        setItemSelectedState(false, position, Color.WHITE);
                    else
                        setItemSelectedState(true, position, Color.LTGRAY);
                }
                @Override
                public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {}

                private void setItemSelectedState(boolean isSelected, int position, int color) {
                    try {
                        listOfUrl.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(color);
                        selectedItems.add(position, isSelected);
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            })
    );
    find.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this); }
```

any on can tell me what i did wrong.

Comment: Are you mutating the List you pass into your adapter somewhere else?  If so, are you informing the adapter that the List has been mutated?

Comment: what do you mean by mutating?

Comment: Adding to or removing from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, create interface class:

```
public interface ListListener {
    void onClick(int pos);
    void onLongClick(int pos);
}
```

Adjust the content of your RecyclerViewAdapter class:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

private ListListener listener;
private List<ItemView> items;
private Context context;

public ListAdapter(List<ItemView> items, Context context) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_style, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

public ItemView getItem(int pos) {
    return items.get(pos);
}

public void setListener(ListListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ItemView i = items.get(position);

    holder.setHeadText(i.getHead());
    holder.setScoreText(i.getContent());

    holder.itemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (listener != null && pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    listener.onClick(pos);
                }
            }
    });

    holder.itemLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                        int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                        if (pos != -1) {
                            if (listener != null) {
                                listener.onLongClick(getItem(pos));
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
}
```

And in your Activity class I edited some parts:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_url_list);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    database = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    listOfUrl = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.url_list);
    find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findBtn);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

    makeItPopUp();

    listOfUrl.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listOfUrl.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listOfUrl.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    adapter = new ListAdapter(fillList(), context);
    adapter.setListener(new SelectCountryDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int pos) {
                ItemView item = adapter.getItem(pos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(int pos) {
                ItemView item = adapter.getItem(pos);
            }
        });
    listOfUrl.setAdapter(adapter);

    selectedItems = new ArrayList<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[listOfUrl.getAdapter().getItemCount()]));
    Collections.fill(selectedItems, Boolean.FALSE);

    find.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this); 
}
```

I'm pretty sure, that now it is very easy for you. Just to implement the functionality in onClick and onLongClick methods.